# EntityFrameworkCore Mapping Relationships

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-core

I have the following two entities:

```
public class Company
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Town { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

This corresponds to two DB tables:

```
Company:
  Id uniqueidentifier
  Name varchar

Address:
  Id uniqueidentifier
  Town varchar
  Country varchar
  RelationId uniqueidentifier
```

RelationId is the foreign key which stores the link back to CompanyId.

I **can not** change either the classes or the tables.

I am trying to figure out how to represent this construct in code first EFCore.

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Company>().ToTable("Companies");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Address>().ToTable("Addresses");

        modelBuilder.Entity<Company>().HasKey(c => c.Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Address>().HasKey(c => c.Id);

        ???????????????????????
    }
```

What am I missing in the code above to prevent the creation of a CompanyId foreign key and use the 'RelationId' instead.

Answer (score 2):

Create a `Guid` RelationId and a `Company` Company properties in Address, as purposed by @TanvirArjel and use the following fluent configuration:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    .....

    modelBuilder.Entity<Company>()
        .HasOne(c => c.Address)
        .WithOne(a => a.Company)
        .HasForeignKey(a => a.RelationId);
}
```

If an address can have more than one company, change the `WithOne` by `WithMany` and the Company property type to `ICollection<Company>`

Answer (score 1):

**Here is the solution for your requirement :**

```
public class Company
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    //remove virtual keyword as there is no lazy loading in  entityframework core
    public ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Company ")]
    public Guid RelationId { get; set; }
    public string Town { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }

    //remove virtual keyword as there is no lazy loading in  entityframework core
    public Company Company {get; set;}
}
```

**Using Fluent API:**

```
public class YourDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Company> Companies { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Address> Addresses { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Address>()
            .HasOne(p => p.Company)
            .WithMany(b => b.Addresses);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any way of doing this in a fluent mapping rather then data annotations?

Comment: Yes! But why do you need when data annotation serving your purpose properly??

Comment: To keep mappings out of the domain classes, it's also the team culture and I would like to follow that.

Comment: Also you don't need fluent configuration in this case. EF will pick up pair of navigation and form one-to-many relationship automatically.